# continuous communication (rather server-> application) in the background

Tags: android, apache, server, communication

hypothetical task:
I want to have an android app - which in real-time (on-line) receives commands from my server and, for example, displays a message - how to accomplish such a task - conceptually - where to start?
I am referring to the interaction in the background and the rapid response of the application - for example imap or instant messaging - what is the protocol / way of communicating with the application?

Answer (score 0):

It is so called push technology, I found something like https://quickblox.com/developers/SimpleSample-messages_users-android

Minus score was unnecessary ;)